# Mongodb in operator in find Query

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I have a query as mentioned below.

```
        var projstat = ['A' , 'B'];
        Post.native(function(err, collection) {

            if (err)
                console.log(err);

            collection.find({
                'status': {
                    "$in": projstat
                }
            }, {multi: true}, function(err, result) {

                console.log(result);
                if (req.isSocket) {
                    return res.json(result);
                }
            });
        });
```

Please correct me if i am wrong as it doesnot return any results. Please help.

Comment: why do you use `multi:true`? Try excluding it

Comment: initially i didnt give multi : true , still i didnt get the results ..So i just tried giving that.

Comment: you are not modifying documents, you are querying; multi option is used when you want to modify several of them... anyway did u try to run the command on console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the native `find` correctly; rather than using a callback as an argument (like Waterline does), you chain the call to `toArray` and use the callback as *its* argument:

```
 collection.find({
   'status': {
      "$in": projstat
   }
 }).toArray(function(err, results) {...});
```

Docs for the native Mongo driver are [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find).

However, the more important point in this case is that you don't need `native` at all.  You can use the regular Waterline `find`, which automatically does an `in` query when an attribute is set to an array:

```
 Post.find({status: projstat}).exec(function(err, results) {...});
```